How to make object cut into another object and leave a hole behind?
I am attempting to make an animation, and I am going to use a knife object to cut into another object, say, apple. In real life, when you cut something, it leaves its cut in the object. I was hoping I could simply use boolean, but that only keeps the hole there as long as the knife object is also there. Any suggestions?
This is what I don't want:

Edit: This question was closed, because a similar question had a question already. I tried that solution, but I forgot a detail. The knife won't just be moving up and down. It will move other ways. If I use that question's answer, I get this:

I need something else that accommodates this extra movement. Also, I'd prefer not to make a duplicate object.

just duplicate your knife object, and make the original(cutter) not move up and make it invisible. [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/7AJtHAze.gif Left: just the cutter animation, right: both

@Chris Interesting. I'll try that. Although I do wish that I didn't need an extra object in the first place.

What do you mean it will move other ways? Like in the comments of the other solution, you could use a curve and make the cutter object follow that. Or do you mean move it arbitrary manually in real-time? This will not work with the Boolean modifier... maybe you should take a look in Dynamic Paint.

@GordonBrinkmann Hmm. I'm talking about the fact that it will move out from the object and then be set down (animation). And, I will probably be moving it in realtime (auto-keying animation). Can Dynamic Paint do such things?

@KidWithGlasses Theoretically yes. When you start running an animation and then move the "brush" over the "canvas", it will react in "real-time". I use real-time here carefully, because for a result like this (here the cutter is following a curve): dynamic paint cutter I used a high resolution to get a relatively smooth cut. But then it is computational expensive, and "real-time" might be slow and choppy. So I would record the movement with auto-keying without Dynamic Paint and then add the effect later when I have the movement.

@moonboots But when you want to move it in real-time and/or recording the movement with auto-keying it might be difficult to recreate the path so that you can keep the cut in place...

@GordonBrinkmann Yes, it would be very difficult to make the path. I'm open to addons (free) if necessary (or easier).

I would use several pieces, when you cut an object like you show in your animation there's not a hole, the pieces get separated

@moonboots The vase in the animation at the end is not separated, there is a cut in the front wall. And I'm not sure if using several pieces makes it easier for real-time animation but maybe I do not understand how it's meant.

Since Blender 3.6 you can use Geometry Nodes for that effect:

With the result visible on the leftmost image:
  
The middle image is better - it's the exact same stuff, just the animation of the cutter scaled up 10× and the FPS increased from standard 24 to 60 so you don't lose that much of your life watching it. One problem with this approach is that time interpolation doesn't affect the simulation so you need to manually scale your animation's f-curves. The 3rd animation is without f-curves scaling, instead it uses a trick of taking a convex hull of current and previous cutter positions:

Keep in mind all 3 animations are rendered in Blender rather than just screen-recorded. They don't showcase performance - you should expect a poor performance with boolean (though I'm surprised it worked as well as it did).
Blender v. 4.1.1

